# Add / Remove 1 day with Moment.js in React

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I have a div with 2 dates inside, for example (< march 25th - march 26th >), and there are 2 arrows "<" and ">"

If a user presses the "<" arrow, I need to remove 1 day to the 2 dates :
(< march 25th - march 26th >) becomes (< march 24th - march 25th >),

and if a user presses the ">" arrow, I need to add 1 day to the 2 dates :
(< march 25th - march 26th >) becomes (< march 26th - march 27th >),

I stored the 2 dates in hooks, and by default, the firstValue is the day of today and the secondValue is 1 week later

```
const [firstValue, setFirstValue] = useState(
    moment(new Date()).format("dddd Do MMMM YYYY")
  );
const [secondValue, setSecondValue] = useState(
    moment(new Date())
      .add(1, "weeks")
      .format("dddd Do MMMM YYYY")
);
```

I tried this when the user presses the "<" arrow :

```
function previousDay() {
    console.log(firstValue, secondValue);
    setFirstValue(moment(firstValue).remove(1, "days"));
    setSecondValue(moment(secondValue).remove(1, "days"));
}
```

but I have the error

```
TypeError: moment__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...)(...).remove is not a function
```

Can somebody know how can I do that

Comment: Well your state object is a `string`, not `moment` object, and `remove` is not a valid operation on a `string`.

Comment: Instead of "remove" you need to use "subtract".
One change I recommend is to do the `.format()` on the render, not on the state. this way you store the moment object instead a string, so you don't need to `moment(value)` again

Comment: So, just do: `setFirstValue(firstValue.subtract(1, "days")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my comments, I'd suggest the following changes:

```
const [firstValue, setFirstValue] = useState(
    moment(new Date()) // remove .format() here
  );
const [secondValue, setSecondValue] = useState(
    moment(new Date())
      .add(1, "weeks")
);
```

On your render:

```
render() {
  <>
    ...
    ...
    {firstValue.format("dddd Do MMMM YYYY")}
  </>
}
```

And your function should be something like:

```
function previousDay() {
    setFirstValue(firstValue.subtract(1, "days")); // don't need to moment() anymore
    setSecondValue(secondValue.subtract(1, "days"));
}
```

Comment: Hello, I did that but I still have a new error: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_isAMomentObject, _i, _isUTC, _pf, _locale, _d, _isValid}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: How is your render function? Can you share it?

Answer (score 0):

Change to :

```
function previousDay() {
    console.log(firstValue, secondValue);
    setFirstValue(moment(firstValue).subtract(1, "days"));
    setSecondValue(moment(secondValue).subtract(1, "days"));
}
```

Because "remove" is **not** a valid property of [Moment object].

Comment: Hello, I did that but I still have a new error: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_isAMomentObject, _i, _isUTC, _pf, _locale, _d, _isValid}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Comment: That problem comes from render method. Show me render method to able to find the issue.

Comment: now the add works, but the substract don't work, I have TypeError: moment_moment__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__(...).substract is not a function

Comment: add and subtract has the same logic, but I can't use the substract method, is there a specific version of moment to use this ?

Comment: oh sh*t i was using subStract instead of subtract, everything is working thank you

Comment: @Versifiction: Congrats! If you feel the answers helpful please vote.